# Name of associative model in CakePHP

Tags: php, arrays, cakephp, associations

At first sorry for my English.
I've got a problem in associative models in CakePHP. When I bind more than two models, for example

```
    $this->Album->bindModel(
                array(
                    'hasMany'=>array(
                        'Photo'=>array(
                            'className'=>'Photo'
                        ),
                        'Album'=>array(
                            'className'=>'Album'
                        )
                    )
                )
            );
```

I have:

```
Array
(
    [Album] => Array
        (
            [id] => 22
            [f_name] => Some album
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 19
                    [f_name] => Another album
                    [id_parent] => 22
                    [Photo] => Array
                        (
....
```

Is it any way to **set** a key in parent table? I mean I don't want to have "0" as a key, there can be "Album1", "Album2" and so on.

Answer (score 0):

The problem likely stems from binding a model to itself under the same name. Album hasMany Album probably trips up Cake somewhere. Use a unique name for the association, like Album hasMany SubAlbum.

Comment: I know there is a model in its own model. I wrote an example, in facet there are other tables. There is some kind of hierarchy tree of objects. One object has children-objects of the same type (Album->Album), or another type (Album->Photo). 
Anyway - how to set a alias of model in associations?

Comment: You're already almost there:
`$this->Album->bindModel(
 array(
  'hasMany'=>array(
   'SomeOtherName'=>array(
    'className'=>'Photo'
   )
  )
 )
);`